# Mysql update query/procedure

Tags: java, mysql, procedure

I have a table with 2 columns, user and userMessage with table name as **Messages**
I have another table with 2 columns as user and userMessageCount with table name as **MessageCount**.
I am very new to programming. I need to write an update query or procedure something that will count the number of messages per user from **Messages** and store the count in **MessageCount**.

I am not able to understand the proper way of doing this. I understand this is a very basic question and I should study to solve this. i am running very late for a deadline. Please help me on this query.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: What do you want? query or procedure? What you have done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Insert Into MessageCount 
Select user, count(*)
From Messages
Group by user
```

Comment: Exact answer. You understood me perfectly.